# Creating account class in java and output

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm trying to create an account class in java. My main issue is not with the class itself but with the output. In short I'm using an array to store bank account information and then checking for an id after to deposit/withdraw a certain amount. My issue is that when I try typing in an invalid value for the id (this is for the checking/searching portion) I should get an output of "account not found" however, for some reason I end up getting five outputs of the same line "account not found" (probably has to do something with the array size but I can't quite figure it out). Is there a way to get it to only print out the line once?

**tl;dr: When typing an invalid Id I should only get one line of "account not found", getting multiple instead**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AccountDriver
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
     int id =0;
     double balance = 0;
     double interest = 0;
     Account[] accounts = new Account[5];
     //this part fills in the array by asking the user information about each account
     System.out.println("Enter the annual interest rate ");
     interest = kb.nextDouble(); 
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
        System.out.println("Enter the account number: ");
        id = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the initial amount to deposit: ");
        balance = kb.nextDouble();
        Account a = new Account(id,balance,interest);
        accounts[i] = a;
    }
    boolean repeat = true;
    boolean found = false;
    while(repeat)
    {
        System.out.println("\n\n*******************************");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the BANK OF AMERICA");
        System.out.println("\n\n*******************************");
        System.out.println("Enter the account number to deposit, withdraw money :");
        id = kb.nextInt();
        int i = 0;
        while (!found && i < 5) 
        {

          if(id == accounts[i].getId())
              {

              System.out.println("Here is the account information currently:");
              System.out.println(accounts[i]);
              System.out.println("*******************");
              System.out.println("Enter the amount of deposit: ");
              double depositAmount = kb.nextDouble();
              accounts[i].deposit(depositAmount);
              System.out.println("Enter the amount to withdraw: ");
              double withdrawAmount = kb.nextDouble();
              if(!accounts[i].withdraw(withdrawAmount))
              {
                 System.out.println("*******Not enough money in your account*********");
              }
              else
              {   
                 System.out.println("Here is the account information after your transaction:");
                 System.out.println(accounts[i]);
              }   
          }
          **//confused about this part** 
          else
          {
              System.out.println("Account not found");
          }
          i++;   
  } 
     //this asks the user if they have any other accounts to continue running the program
     System.out.println("\nDo you have any other account?");
     String answer = kb.next();
     if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
     {
        repeat = false;       
     }
  }  
}
```

}

**Here's the class if anyone needs it**

```
public class Account{

//These are instance variables
private static double annualInterestRate;
private int id;
private double balance;
//This creates an object from the date class in java  
private java.util.Date dateCreated;

//This no argument constructor creates a default account
public Account() 
{

   dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
   id = 0;
   balance = 0;
   annualInterestRate = 0;
}
//This constructor creates an account with
public Account(int newId, double newBalance, double newAnnualInterestRate) 
{
  //initialize the instance variables to the given values
  dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
  id = newId;
  balance = newBalance;
  annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;

}
//accessors (get)fill in the following methods
public int getId() 
{
  return id;
}
public double getBalance() 
{
    return balance;
}
public static double getAnnualInterestRate() 
{
   return annualInterestRate;
}
//mutators (get)
public void setId(int newId) 
{
     if (newId > 0)
     {
        id = newId;
     }

}
public void setBalance(double newBalance) 
{
     if(newBalance >0)
     {
        newBalance = balance;
     }

}
public static void setAnnualInterestRate(double newAnnualInterestRate)
{
   if(newAnnualInterestRate > 0)
   {
     newAnnualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
   }

}
public double getMonthlyInterest() 
{
   double monthlyInterest = (balance * annualInterestRate/100 / 12);
   return monthlyInterest;
}
public java.util.Date getDateCreated() 
{
   return dateCreated;
}
//this boolean method checks to see if the user has enough money to withdraw
public boolean withdraw(double amount) 
{

  if(amount > balance)
  {
     return false;
  }
  else
  {
     balance = balance - amount;
     return true;
  }
}
//this method returns the balance after the user enters an amount to deposit
public double deposit(double amount) 
{
   balance = balance + amount;
   return balance;   
} 
//this method compares two accounts
public boolean equals(Account a)
{
   return this.id  == a.id;
}
//this method outputs the account information for each account
public String toString()
{
   String s = "";
   s = s + "ID: " + id;
   s = s + String.format("\nBalance:  %.2f", balance);
   s = s + "\nAnnual interest rate: " + annualInterestRate;
   double value = getMonthlyInterest();
   s = s + String.format( "\nmonthly interest: %.2f", value);
   s = s + "\nDate account created: " + dateCreated;
   return s;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a Break after your System.out.println();

```
      else{
          System.out.println("Account not found");

          //this will break your loop;
          break;
      }
```

or set your `found` to `true`

```
      else{
          System.out.println("Account not found");

          //this will stop your inner while loop;
          found = true;
      }
```

## Updated

i found out a lot of lapses on your code.

**fix #1**  : put your `boolean found = false;` inside you outer loop `while(repeat)` because you are going to change the value of that boolean variable later on inside your inner while loop.  move your `boolean found = false;` after this declaration `int i = 0;`

**fix #2**  : after your transaction ends put a `found = true;` after your `System.out.println(accounts[i]);`

**reason**  : this is to stop your inner while loop.

**fix #3**  : on your else condition put a `if` condition that will verify if there are no more next account. before terminating your inner loop.

```
      else{
        // i == 4 will return true after the loop reached the last account.
        if(i == 4){
            System.out.println("Account not found");
            // this is to stop the inner loop if no account found .
            found = true;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Tried it and it works but it breaks my program, I can no longer search for an id (it just keeps outputting "account not found" even for a valid id.) Any fix for that?

Comment: @user4147933 how about the second solution ?

Comment: Wow yeah that did it, thanks a bunch! I've been struggling for hours haha. Thanks again.